# ManyToMany with CascadeType.ALL results in Detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a many to many relationship with Users and Roles. The user is the owner of the relationship and has CascadeType.ALL. When i'm seeding the database, I first create users, create roles and assign the roles to the users. Afterwards I save all users with the repository.

I would imagine since I'm saving users, the roles also get saved in the database because of the cascadetype but the error I'm getting is the one mentioned in the title.

User:

```
@Entity
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name = "users_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Role> roles;
```

Role:

```
@Entity
public class Role {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany
private List<User> users;
```

The code used for seeding the database:

```
        User user1= new User();
        User user2= new User();

        Role role1 = new Role();
        Role role2 = new Role();

        user1.addRole(role1);
        user2.addRole(role1);
        user2.addRole(role2);

        role1.addUser(user1);
        role1.addUser(user2);
        role2.addUser(user2);

        userRepository.save(user1);
        userRepository.save(user2);
```

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I found that the problem only occurs when I add multiple roles to the same user and have updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

**Your Cascading here is wrong.** Having Cascade.ALL on a many to many collection does not make sense exactly because you can have Roles that are shared across users.

What hibernate is trying to tell you is that you already have a role that has associated ID and the you are trying to invoke persist on the same role.

You need to figure out how to manage your roles. You have two options:

1. Remove the cascading.
2. Reasign the managed roles to your user2, so that you are not using the detached one.

Personaly I would remove the Cascade.ALL. IMO it is wrong.

Comment: I had also thought about the use of cascade.ALL and have decided to get rid of it now. Doing this leads me to another little problem though. Adding a new user to the database with existing roles gives me a "object references an unsaved transient instance" error because the roles from the new user dont get persisted. Would you have any idea how to get around this? When I tried this scenario with the cascade.ALL still active, I got another error saying that the role I'm trying to persist is a duplicate entry. Do you have any advice? Much appreciated!

Comment: Are you saving in the same transaction ?

Comment: I think what is happening if you are saving within the same transaction is that hen you save the second user the Role that has been already saved in the previously does not have the same ID and Version. Try flushing and refreshing the roles before the second save.

Comment: You know if you kdon't have Cascading you need to manage the order of the insertions updates yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This example works for me, no exception there. Please share more info: hibernate version, database and the actual code that you're running.

Comment: I have edited the code. Apparently my error only occurs when adding multiple roles to a user.

Comment: In the following code the problem is that to role1 you added also user2. When you saves user1 it also saves role1 which has user2 which is not saved. So you need to save user2 firstly or add cascade type to Role also.